# $ bundle update - error - Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq) *** extconf.rb failed ***

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, bundle, bundler

I'm trying to run
$bundle update, but it errors after going through several gems with the following:

```
Installing pg (0.11.0) with native extensions /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /opt/local/lib/postgresql83/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
    --with-libpqlib
    --without-libpqlib
    --with-ms/libpqlib
    --without-ms/libpqlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.11.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.11.0/ext/gem_make.out
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in `build_extensions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:100:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/cli.rb:252:in `update'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/bin/bundle:13
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

Have you seen this or have any ideas on what's breaking here? thanks

Comment: I need to use Postgres with rails 3. commenting out gem 'pg' #Postgres in the gemfile makes the bundle update work fine. Should I not be using the pg gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked by running:

```
sudo bundle install
```

Comment: I know this is a few years old, but these days (2014) bundler gives you a warning when doing this:  


`Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle
as root will break this application for all non-root users on this machine.`

Answer (score 3):

When you tried to compile a postgres gem to the ruby, you have to have installed a development version of Posgtresql library, in Ubuntu (Debian etc.) it is named libpq-dev and client library, which is named libpqx (x is the version of this library).